# Transaction commit delay when routing message from one jms queue to another

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss5.x, mule

We are trying to build simple transacted jms-to-jms router using Mule ESB and JBoss Messaging. When we run Mule ESB with application configured as below, we observe strange behaviour.

1. Approximately 10 messages are routed from queue test1 to test2
2. Nothing happens for ~40 seconds.
3. goto 1

Queue test1 is filled with around 500 messages when we start test. We use Mule 3.2 and JBoss 5.1.

If I remove transactions from code below everything works fine, all messages are sent to queue test2 instantly. Also, everything is fine if I change transactions from xa to jms -- by replacing xa-transaction tags with jms:transaction.

I don't know what causes this pause in message processing on ESB, probably transaction commit is delayed.

My question is: what should I do to have xa transactions working correctly?

I'll provide more details if needed. I asked this question on Mule ESB forum before with no answer http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/transaction_commit_delay_when_routing_message_from_one_jms_queue_to_another

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jbossts="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts" version="CE-3.2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts/current/mule-jbossts.xsd ">
    <jbossts:transaction-manager> </jbossts:transaction-manager>
    <configuration>  
        <default-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="30" maxThreadsIdle="5"/>  
        <default-receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="10" maxThreadsIdle="5"/> 
    </configuration>
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="jmsJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate" doc:name="Bean">
            <spring:property name="environment">
                <spring:props>
                    <spring:prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="jnp.disableDiscovery">true</spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="java.naming.provider.url">localhost:1099</spring:prop>
                </spring:props>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" doc:name="Bean">
            <spring:property name="jndiTemplate">
                <spring:ref bean="jmsJndiTemplate"/>
            </spring:property>
            <spring:property name="jndiName">
                <spring:value>XAConnectionFactory</spring:value>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>
    <jms:connector name="JMS" specification="1.1" numberOfConsumers="10" connectionFactory-ref="jmsConnectionFactory" doc:name="JMS"/>
    <flow name="flow" doc:name="flow">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="test1" connector-ref="JMS" doc:name="qt1">
            <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="test2" connector-ref="JMS" doc:name="qt2">
            <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/NnykvUDd) you can find log fragment for 1 message interaction. Please note that in this case there was no delay.
And [here](http://pastebin.com/V7EnKXtM) is log fragment for 11 messages. All of them were in queue test1 when app started, as you can see 10 messages are routed instantly and one is delayed by 1 minute.

Comment: Are the transactions correctly committed after this delay or do they rollback? Can you set Mule log level to DEBUG and share the log entries for *1* message interaction (ie. drop one message in 'test1' queue)?

Comment: Delayed transactions are correctly commited, messages appear in queue test2. I added logs to question that show interactions for 1 and 11 messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found root of my problem: my queues were defined with following attribute:

```
   <attribute name="RedeliveryDelay">60000</attribute>
```

Removing it or setting low value solves my problem with delays. Problem is, I don't know why :)

I always thought that redelivery delay is used when delivery fails, which was not the case in my app.

Comment: Did you find out why does it happen?